# How to disable thread safety in PHP?

Tags: php, thread-safety

I am using some software that requires me to have thread safety disabled. I am working on a Windows server. From what I've read elsewhere, I can't just configure this in the .ini file. Is this true? If so, how would I compile it so that thread safety is turned off?

Comment: This seems dangerous... disabling thread safety in a web app?

Comment: It's store locator software from Ultimate Locator. Not too sure what's going on behind the scenes, but I guess they've got their bases covered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to compile PHP with ZTS disabled (compile flag `--disable-zts`) or [download binaries](http://windows.php.net) with ZTS disabled.

This won't work properly in some webservers, namely those which process several PHP scripts simultaneously in the same process.

Comment: This option doesn't exist for PHP 5.2.17, and I can't find anything similar

Comment: I found it, it was because installing `apache2-dev` package on my system (Ubuntu) automatically installs `apache2-thread-dev` whose `apxs2` tells the PHP build system to build with thread-safety on. Therefore, the solution was to directly install `apache2-prefork-dev` package.

Answer (score 3):

You can download compiled non-thread-safe binaries of PHP for Windows from

- http://windows.php.net/download/

Answer (score 2):

It is  *--disable-maintainer-zts* command. May try  *--disable-posix-threads* to.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the last version of Zend Optimizer which have the thread safety on http://downloads.zend.com/optimizer/3.3.0/ZendOptimizer-3.3.0-linux-glibc23-x86_64.tar.gz