# Cannot loadExtension in SQLite3 module, PHP

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, xampp

I need to use extension `example.dll` with SQLite3 object in PHP. Extension has non-standard entry point `custom_init`.  `sqlite3.extension_dir` in php.ini is specified properly. Tried the following code:

```
$dbconn = new SQLite3('test.db');
$dbconn->loadExtension('example.dll');
$dbconn->exec("SELECT load_extension('example.dll');");
```

As one can see, I used two approches to load it.

First approach: `$dbconn->loadExtension('sqldba.dll');`.

- Doesn't work on my XAMPP/Apache with error `Not supported in multithreaded Web servers`, albeit it is done especially for this. What can be wrong in XAMPP/Apache configuration?
- On one not so well-known HTTP server it returns 'Unable to load extension' because of non-standard entry point. Can I specify custom entry point somehow?

Second approach: `$dbconn->exec("SELECT load_extension('example.dll', 'custom_init');");`.

- Fails with error `not authorized`. Is there any way to call sqlite3_enable_load_extension here? I can't find such function in "SQLite for PHP" module documentation.

Upd: somehow related: [How to load sqlite extension in PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756146/how-to-load-sqlite-extension-in-pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Not supported in multithreaded Web servers"

This won't work on IIS anyway, which is (apperently) preferable for me. According to [this (line 414)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sqlite3/sqlite3.c) it is only enabled in ZTS(Zend Thread Safety). Disabling it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425514/how-to-disable-thread-safety-in-php). Still no idea what's wrong with Apache config.

- 'Unable to load extension' because of non-standard entry point. Can I specify custom entry point somehow?

Nnnope. Maybe someone should add a "custom entry point" feature request to PHP tracker, it doesn't seem that difficult.

- `"SELECT load_extension('example.dll', 'custom_init');"` - fails with error "not authorized".

You have to call `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` before doing load_extension from query, and there is no analogue of `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` in php-sqlite. Patching PDO-Sqlite for this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756146/how-to-load-sqlite-extension-in-pdo), but it's very unsafe. Adding this as new feature in php-sqlite would be much better.