# RHEL PHP 8.0 Non-Thread Safe Compilation

Tags: php, multithreading, rhel, non-thread-safe

I have an application that I need to be using a non-thread-safe(nts) version of php 8.0 being built on current RHEL. I have tried a few different ways of recompiling php including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425514/how-to-disable-thread-safety-in-php) to no avail. Checking the php info page, It still says that thread safety is enabled. Does anyone know of a way to recompile PHP without thread safety? I have found many posts talking about enabling thread safety, but almost nothing on disabling it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Compiling on RHEL 8 for RHEL 8.

Comment: Ok, on windows if I remember correctly it compiles and links both a TS and non TS version. Do you have a directory at the end of the make process called `Release` and `Release_TS`

Comment: I did not see two distinct directories, only a 'Release' dir.

Comment: Point 16 in here may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098829/2310830

Comment: I will give it a try and see if it helps. If it works, I will come put that as the solution.